# Significance of blue flowers in What dreams may come

Tags: analysis, what-dreams-may-come

In ["What dreams may come"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Dreams_May_Come_%28film%29), blue flowers are ubiquitous. What do they represent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the "production notes" issued by the [Director's own website](http://vincentwardfilms.com/films/what-dreams-may-come/gallery/production-stills/), the [Jacaranda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacaranda) flowers have a dual meaning, representing....

- **[Annie's grief](http://vincentwardfilms.com/concepts/wdmc/treatment/) (at the loss of their children) made substantive as Chris walks through *her* paintings**

  > *When Chris (Robin Williams) dies he finds himself in an afterlife that
  >   emulates his wife Annie’s work: She restored nineteenth century
  >   paintings, and in her spare time painted pictures which reflect
  >   elements of their life together. **Now Chris finds himself walking
  >   within her living paintings.***

  [image]
- **[Chris' grief](http://vincentwardfilms.com/cms/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/DreamsInterscope.pdf) at the loss of his family when Annie left him (and obviously their subsequent deaths)**

  > *"And I always imagined Chris, the last time he saw his children,
  >   standing there with the van going away, under these trees and the
  >   whole street covered in leaves, in these blue Jacaranda leaves. And,
  >   **every time he would think of his children, from then on, through the
  >   rest of the movie, somewhere in that shot would be a color that was
  >   Jacaranda purple."***

  [image]

Comment: This is not strictly related to this movie, but there is an ancient precedent for flowers in the underworld, namely the asphodel.  William Carlos Williams wrote an interesting poem about it: *["So that I was cheered when I came first to know that there were flowers also in hell."](https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poem/asphodel-greeny-flower-excerpt)*